# C++ anachronisms explained

Tags: c++

I am getting some warning messages when compiling C++ code using Sun Studio and that is related to anachronisms. Can somebody please explain me what is anachronisms in C++?

Also how to turn off these warning messages in Sun Studio.

Thanks
Niraj Rathi

Comment: Please copy-paste the warning messages

Comment: Anachronisms would be "things we accept for the sake of backward compatibility, but don't really like". Given how out of date Sun Studio was at least the last time I looked, this probably implies "Cro-Magnon C++ detected."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anachronisms are "features" that are borrowed from older languages such as C or BCPL, and do not belong in modern code.

An example would be a non-`const` pointer to a string literal:

```
char* p = "Hello World!";
```

The best way to get rid of the warnings is to fix the code.  In the above example, you would use `const`-correctness:

```
const char* p = "Hello World!";
```